# Why does my loop in Visual Studio Jquery never stops?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, for-loop

currently i need my for loop to run for 10 times and stop, however it just keeps on running even thou i had set a limit for it. Any advice ?

```
function adder() {
var fromvalue;
fromvalue = localStorage.getItem("Fromvalue");

var tovalue;
tovalue = localStorage.getItem("Tovalue");

var conversionvalue;
conversionvalue = localStorage.getItem("Conversionvalue");

var tonumber;
tonumber = $("#txtTo1").val();

var fromnumber;
fromnumber = $("#txtFrom1").val();



var fromtotal;
fromtotal = fromnumber + 10;

var result;

for (a = fromnumber; a <= fromtotal; a++) {
    result = a * conversionvalue;
    alert("From " + a + fromvalue + "To " + result + tovalue);
}
```

Comment: try using `parseInt($("#txtFrom1").val(), 10)` - you need to make the values into ints before adding, otherwise you are probably just appending text

Comment: Thanks Pete, it worked wonders for me. Any ideas on how to display it into a table instead of an alert?

Comment: @EddieLee Create your table structure in HTML then append something like `'<tr><td> From '  + a + fromvalue + 'To ' + result + tovalue + '</td></tr>'` to it within your for loop.

Comment: I get it master yoda, however i need to print the results of my loop when the user clicks a button and a dialog box should appear. I cant seem to get a table into a dialog box without screwing up my html, any ideas about this ?

Comment: This should help with the appending: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Comment: thanks all for help, i solved it (: